# Recursive data scraping in excel sheets within nested folder structure

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, openpyxl

Help me out please. I would like to traverse through a directory structure that looks like this:

Topdir > subdir 1 > excel 1/2/3

Topdir > subdir 2 > excel 4

etc

I am scraping the excel's column B for a string, and that is working nicely. However, my script only goes through the topdir, and doesn't go into the subdirs. Below is my code:

```
import openpyxl, os, sys, warnings, glob

warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
targetString = str("Sample Error")
scriptPath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
outputFile = open('logging.txt', "w+")


def scrapeSheets():
    for i in os.listdir(path='.'):
        if i.endswith("data-eval.xlsm"):
            print("Working on:", i)
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(i, data_only=True)
            sheet = wb["data-sheet"]
            outputFile.write("{}\n".format(i))
            for cellObj in sheet["B"]:
                if cellObj.value == targetString:
                    print(cellObj.row, cellObj.value)
                    outputFile.write("\t{}\t{}\n".format(cellObj.row, cellObj.value))

def mainLoop():
    for filename in glob.iglob('**/*.xlsm', recursive=True):
        scrapeSheets()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mainLoop()
```

As I said, the scraping works, but I cannot go into the subfolders. I have a hunch it has to do with the line

```
 for i in os.listdir(path='.')
```

however, I don't know the solution to make the loop's variable increment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
    for dirname in os.listdir(path='.'):
        for main_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
            for f in files:
                if f.endswith("data-eval.xlsm"):
                    print("Working on:", f)
                    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f, data_only=True)
                    sheet = wb["data-sheet"]
                    outputFile.write("{}\n".format(i))
                    for cellObj in sheet["B"]:
                        if cellObj.value == targetString:
                            print(cellObj.row, cellObj.value)
                            outputFile.write("\t{}\t{}\n".format(cellObj.row, cellObj.value))
```

Explanation:

Using `listdir` iterate over the directories.

```
for dirname in os.listdir(path='.')
```

Iterate over the sub-directories and the files inside those using :

```
for main_dir, dirs, files in os.walk(dirname):
```

Iterate over the files and continue your logic.

```
            for f in files:
            if f.endswith("data-eval.xlsm"):
                print("Working on:", f)
                wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f, data_only=True)
                sheet = wb["data-sheet"]
                outputFile.write("{}\n".format(i))
                for cellObj in sheet["B"]:
                    if cellObj.value == targetString:
                        print(cellObj.row, cellObj.value)
                        outputFile.write("\t{}\t{}\n".format(cellObj.row, cellObj.value))
```

Comment: With your suggestion I get: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.xlsm' as it is trying to look in the script's directory, but not beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I figured out that implementing the *for filename in glo.iglob* part in the scraping function instead the *os.listdir* line works perfectly and loops through the content of the script's folder and its subfolders.